# phpmyadmin is stuck at login (nginx server)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm running nginx along with fastcgi-php to get php working for phpmyadmin. (I'm developing with Rails primarily.) I'm running everything from a local server on my network.

The rails app is functional. The login screen for phpmyadmin appears and phpinfo() works as well, but when attempting to login to phpmyadmin, I'm thrown back to the login screen with no visible errors.

I'm assuming I may have misconfigured something with the server or have yet to configure phpmyadmin properly.

Here's the relevant code block in nginx.cong=f

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /home/dev/spindle/public;
        rails_env development;
        passenger_enabled on;`

        access_log logs/host.access.log;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

       location /phpmyadmin{  
            root    /usr/share;  
            index   index.php;  
       }  

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            set $php_root   /home/dev/spindle/public;  
                if ($request_uri ~* /phpmyadmin) {  
                    set $php_root /usr/share;  
                }  
                fastcgi_index  index.php;  
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
        }  


    }
```

Comment: Check that the PHP session directory is write- and readable.

Comment: Where can I find that directory?  I checked in /var/lib/php5/ and found nothing.

Comment: It should be named in the `phpinfo()` output. Look for `session.save_path`.

Comment: `chmod a+rw /var/lib/php5` didn't change anything

Comment: @hakre do you have any ideas as to what may still be causing the issue?

Comment: You could Check the PHPMyadmin configuration if it has the right servername and path. As well for cookies, I think it uses cookies for the login. Then double-check if PHPMyadmin is compatible with your nginx and fastcgi.

Comment: What error  do you see?

Comment: @Pazis, note this is a *really* old question, and I don't remember many of the details, but as the question states, there were "no visible errors".

Answer (score 1):

If all your configurations for `phpMyAdmin` are correct but the problem still persists, it could be due lack of disk space. If this is the case, you can use `df -h` to diagnose the space problem.

My scenario was that a cron was used to create mysqldump of a large database until the space ran out. After deleting the sql dumps, `phpMyAdmin` logged in as it should.

Hope it helps.